# How to change a webview's url without using multiple webviews

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, webview, wkwebview

I have an app which I am developing which uses a webview (`WKwebview`). I am using `Swift 3` and `Xcode`

I now have implemented a menu, which the user can click and load up a different site. When the user clicks on a new site, I want the URL from this new site to update the current `webview`. I cant seem to find a way to change the URL and then update the `webview`? Is the only way to create 5 unique `webviews` all hooked up to the corresponding button press?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On the click of your menu item you can simply call the `loadRequest` method with the `URL` object of your web URL which you want to load. Something like below.

`self.webView.loadRequest(request)`

Answer (score 0):

You're menu must a table/button or any UI element which registers a click event. In the click event, create an object of the view controller class in which the webview is and pass the data using that object before you present the view controller with the webview.

In the click event method : -

```
UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle:nil];
SecondViewController *destVC = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier: @"SecondVC"];

destVC.webURL = @"**your web url***";
[self presentViewController:destVC animated:YES completion:nil];
```

where webURL is a property you have to create in the second view controller(you view controller with the webview of NSString type). Use this webURL to populate your webview.